# Hardware switch toggles for laptop modules

Tags: power, switches, laptop

I intend to take the camera, microphone, wifi and bluetooth modules inside a laptop, determine which pin provides them with power and then reflow the solder and bend that pin up so it is not in contact anymore. In each of these cases I then would like to introduce a  very small slide switch in between the bent pin and its closest pad to allow for a physical on/off switch for each of these.

I'll have a simple PCB and then a 3D printed housing for the switches with some manner of clamping system on the rear to hold it in place and route the necessary wiring to and from each switch i a flat cable like mini HDMI or something that's easily concealable and enter the case through a modest hole.

The switches have already been checked to determine that they will function as expected for each of the four systems. My question is really: is there something major I'm not considering?

Answer (score 2):

Cutting the power connection is not sufficient to prevent the peripheral device from functioning.

Most such devices are constructed in a way that has diode junctions from the power supply pins to all of the input/output connections. This is generally an unavoidable side effect of how silicon chips are made. Sometimes these diodes are used to advantage to help protect against a range of ESD damage.

When voltage is applied to input/output connections of an IC that has no other connection to power, the internal power will be drawn from the input/output connections instead. This doesn't work very well, but it can lead to surprises when a device believed to be powered off is actually active despite its power pin being disconnected.

This is more of an issue with battery-powered devices (rather than privacy issues), because any unwanted drain current reduces the available battery runtime. So for the past several decades the various IC manufacturers have addressed this problem by adding shutdown modes (either dedicated shutdown pins or software commands, or both) to inhibit the device activity without switching the power pin.

Answer (score 0):

What do you think will happen when the operating system tries to communicate with these modules? Cutting power is not the same as electrically disconnecting the module...you still have communication signals going to these modules, and a high voltage on one of those communication lines can provide enough current to the module that it kinda sorta functions.

It might work, but there is a good chance that it will not.

Comment: I expect the OS will observe a change in hardware. So far things like unplugging the camera connector, for example, results in the camera being inaccessible and disappearing from the OS listings as if it's not there. I'm glad I asked in advance, though. I had been kind of suspicious about how straight forward this might be...

Comment: How will OS possibly know that the hardware is only partially working? That the logic signal levels may be invalid?